# How do I re-attach the details window in Fiddler after using Tearoff

Tags: fiddler

I clicked the "Tearoff" tab in Fiddler2, which made the details view a separate window.  How to I put the details back into the primary window?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is simple, but counter-intuitive. Simply close the teared off window and it will reappear as a docked pane in the main window.